# I have a question about a disease on my green beans

Tags: beans, green-beans

I'm not sure if this is a disease or a bit as weather-related on my green beans can someone give me any idea, my beans have a purple almost black all over them it's not a texter nor is it slamming I just wonder if it's a disease or just from too much rain

Comment: Can you add a photograph please?